# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a un metodo que tiene un array bidimensional como parametro?

Tags: java

Hola tengo esta duda ya que no soy capaz de llamar a un método que tiene una matriz como parámetro.
Tengo este es el método constructor:

```
public Matriz(int[][] matriz) {
    this.matriz = matriz;
}
```

Pero cuando quiero llamarlo así:

```
Matriz matriz = new Matriz(...);
```

No se que tengo que poner como parámetro. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaría agradecido.

Comment: Como parametro debes pasar justamente un array bidimensional.

Comment: Pero con corchetes, parentesis o como?

Comment: una variable que sea un array bidimensional...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como parámetro deberás pasar justamente una variable de tipo array bidimensional. Ejemplo:

```
int[][] miArray = new int[3][5];
```

Y luego la pasas así:

```
Matriz matriz = new Matriz(miArray);
```

Yo use dimensiones 3 y 5 como ejemplo, pero vos usarás las que necesites.